# How to resolve this error : "Error while generating presigned URL: date.getUTCFullyear is not a function"?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm recently migrating from node v14 to v18 which requires AWS SDK v2 upgrade to v3.
[node v14 to v18](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/)

This is how the implementation went

```
const s3 = new S3Client({ signatureVersion: 'v4' });
 try {
    let command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    if (flag === 'DOWN') {
      command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: params.Bucket,
        Key: params.Key,
      });
      delete params.Metadata;
      logger.info({
        reqp: { headers: { rid } },
        message: `Command invoked is ${command.constructor.name}`,
      });
const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);
```

I think there is some issue with how I'm passing params in getSignedUrl function. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error.  It's because they changed the `Expires` property in the command object to expect a Date.  If you just want to send in the same number of seconds as before, remove it from the command and send it in a configuration object to the `getSignedUrl` function

The answer in this post shows an example.
[How do I use the javascript aws-sdk v3 (or backblaze native apis) to create a signed url to use on the client to upload (put) files to the bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75856471/how-do-i-use-the-javascript-aws-sdk-v3-or-backblaze-native-apis-to-create-a-si)

Comment: This is an example: 
const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, get_command, { expiresIn: 3600 });